# C++ self-defined class return

Tags: c++

I have defined a class,

Aims: simulate the string but with more functionalities

```
class ex_char
{
public:
    ex_char(char *input):len(strlen(input)){strcpy(str,input);}
    ...functions...
private:
    char *str; //where the char array is saved
    int len;   //length of the char array
};
```

For a normal char array, we can use:

```
char charray[10]="String";
cout<<charray;
```

to show the content of the char array

But how can I show the content of my class's str property by

```
cout<<excharray;
```

Comment: overload operator `<<`

Comment: Remember to point `str` to the memory of the enemy before calling `strcpy`...

Comment: Don't you need to allocate memory for `str`? You would be better off using an `std::string`.

Comment: you can also use casting operator to cast to const char *, and output directly.

Comment: NO NO, really not, I will only use the ex_char by pointer, and it dont have much opportunity to change its size, if it really need to change its size, it is the time for me to start a brand new ex_char's string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have finished the functionality correctly(in your exmaple code, you didn't allocate memory for `str`), overload the operator `<<`, so that it can be used like `cout<<excharray;`

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ex_char &my_string)
{
    os << my_string.str;
    return os;
}
```

Since you need `cout` to access some of your class's private elements, you also need to add the operator to `friend`.

Comment: Thank you for this, I almost forget <<override ...

Comment: To be able to do that, one needs to add the operator as friend to the class so that it is able to see `str`; put this in the private part of the class: `friend ostream &operator=(ostream& os, const ex_char &my_string);`

Comment: @flyx Right, added it to the answer.

Comment: why is the friend operator= ? aren't we talking about about operator<< ?

Comment: @Echo That's a typo, I think.